# Unable to load bean using Struts convention plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I want to use annotation based config instead of xml based. Struts has [convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html) to do this kind of thing.

So I removed `struts.xml` file in `main/resources`, added this plugin as dependency, put some annotations on actions and tried to run my project on a server (Tomcat 7).

When the server starts, I get the next stacktrace:

```
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/EclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/shop/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.24.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:32:155
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.convention.ActionConfigBuilder class:org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder - bean - jar:file:/D:/EclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/shop/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.24.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:32:155
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/DefaultClassFinder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2012)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:237)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.DefaultClassFinder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 24 more

черв. 02, 2015 7:52:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/EclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/shop/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.24.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:32:155
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/EclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/shop/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.24.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:32:155
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.convention.ActionConfigBuilder class:org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder - bean - jar:file:/D:/EclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/shop/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.24.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:32:155
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/DefaultClassFinder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2012)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:237)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.DefaultClassFinder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 24 more
```

The thing is that struts has `xwork-core` as dependency, so it lies in classpath, but somehow tomcat can't find it. These are my dependencies from `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>c</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>tld</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>fmt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>tld</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>fn</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>tld</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- struts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- front-end -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>mustachejs</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into maven dependencies the `struts2-core` already has a dependency on `xwork-core`, so it should be downloaded when you build the app. Diffrent versions of plug-ins could make the plugin stop working or it just breaks on startup. You should use the following artifacts

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.24</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes, this was the cause - I tested your solution and it works.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 points wrong in the `pom.xml`
1. `struts2-core` has already included xwork-core
2. version of `struts2-core` should be greater than/equal to version of `structs2-convention-plugin`